Adjusting text size within a long table
I'm having troubles with modifying the size of the font inside a very big table. The table contains description of different physical models.
Although I've set a \newcolumntype{H}{>{\Huge}c} and gave the specific type of colum to my tabular, it doesn't happen to change the font size.
I think I'm close to the solution but I miss some informations to solve it.
Could you please help me? Thank you so much
\begin{table}[t]
    \caption{ A summary of the 12 selected models. * The columns “Country of application” and “Real
        case study” refer to the related cited paper in this review. “WWM” stands for “Wu and Waldron root
        reinforcement model”; “AFBM” stands for “Analytical Fiber Bundle Model” for root reinforcement.}
    \label{tab:oneA}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}[c]{HHHHHH}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{lightgray}Model & Country of Application * & Real Case Study & Hydrology & Vegetation &  \\ \hline
            SHALSTAB \cite{75} &  United States &  \begin{tabular}{c} Tennessee Valley (colluvial soils), \\ Mettman
                Ridge (colluvial soils), \\ Split Creek
                (silty sands)
                \end{tabular} 
            & \begin{tabular}{c}
                Derivation of the critical \\ saturated soil height \\ through TOPOG \cite{76}
            \end{tabular}
             & - & \\ \hline
            dSLAM \cite{77} & United States & \begin{tabular}{c}
                Cedar Creek basin, \\ Oregon Coast
                Range \\ (real landslides
                not well documented)
            \end{tabular}
            & Kinematic wave
            groundwater model \cite{78} & \begin{tabular}{c}
            Mechanical basal root
            reinforcement (WWM) \\ as
            constant C\textsubscript{r} \end{tabular} & \\ \hline
            SHETRAN \cite{79} & \begin{tabular}{c} United Kingdom of
            Great Britain, \\ 
            Northern Ireland\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{c}
            Kirkton research catchment \\ in Balquhidder, Scotland \\ (real landslides
            not well documented)
            \end{tabular}
             & \begin{tabular}{c}
                Lateral flow: Boussinesq
                equation; \\ Vertical flow: 1D
                Richards’ equation; \\ snowmelt
             \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{c} ET, interception, \\ spatially
            variable land use \end{tabular} &  \\ \hline
            \begin{tabular}{c}
                 \\ Iverson \cite{82} \\ \\
            \end{tabular}&  - & - & Reduced form of Richards’
            equation & - &  \\ \hline
            \begin{tabular}{c}
                \\ TRIGRS \cite{84} \\ \\
            \end{tabular} & - & - & Richards’ equation
            per \cite{85} & Extension by \cite{86}
            comprises root cohesion
            and tree surcharge &  \\ \hline
            \begin{tabular}{c}
                \\ SLIP \cite{90} \\ \\
            \end{tabular} & Italy & Different areas of Italy & Increase in the saturated
            portion of the soil
            with rainfall & \begin{tabular}{c}
                Extension by \cite{91} \\ comprises interception \\ and root cohesion
            \end{tabular}
            &  \\ \hline
            \begin{tabular}{c}
                \\ SUSHI \cite{92}  \\ \\
            \end{tabular}& Italy & May 1998 Sarno
            landslides on pyroclastic
            soils from Campania
            (Italy) & 1D Richards’ equation
            (Hydro-SUSHI module) & ET as function of LAI,
            interception &  \\ \hline
            tRIBS-VEGGIE-Landslide \cite{93} & Puerto Rico & Luquillo forest (Puerto
            Rico)—no real landslides  & 1D Richards’ equation
             & \begin{tabular}{c}
                Hydrological effects: \\ transpiration \cite{95}, \\ evaporation reduction by canopies; \\ vegetation variable with
                time, space, and depth \\ (root distribution and root
                water uptake); \\ root cohesion 
             \end{tabular}
            &  \\ \hline
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                \\  MD-STAB \cite{96} \\ \\
            \end{tabular} & United States & November 1996, Coos
            Bay, Mettnam ridge
            debris flow
            (gravelly sand)  & Hydrostatic condition
             & Only mechanical
             reinforcement: basal and
             lateral, variable
             with depth &  \\ \hline
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                \\ SOSlope\cite{98}  \\ \\
             \end{tabular} & - & -  & Macropore water pressure
             and matrix suction
             & Mechanical lateral root
             reinforcement (RBM) &  \\ \hline
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                \\ Lizárraga et al. \cite{99} \\ \\
             \end{tabular} & Italy & May 1998 landslides on
             pyroclastic soils from
             Campania (Italy) & Authors used TRIGRS to
             compute hydrology
             & - &  \\ \hline
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                \\ Abdollahi et al. \cite{102} \\ \\
             \end{tabular}& United States & 2019 Las Lomas
             watershed (California)
             shallow landslide (sandy
             loam and loam soils)  & 1D Richards’ equation
             & ET
             Mechanical basal root
             reinforcement (AFBM)
              &  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}```


never do   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% on a table that gives up any chance of getting consistent font sizes. Remove that then use a suitable font size such as \small  don't just show H in the text of your question, edit the example so it is a complete small document with all needed definitions

essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options
